# Changing Google Stacked Bar Chart colors (Material Bar Chart)

Tags: javascript, charts, material-design

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(stats_data);

var options = {
    width: 1400,
    height: 400,
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,
    bars: 'vertical',
    colors:['#999','#346ac9', '#279423', '#fc9826'],
};

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart-recent'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

I've got a stacked bar chart and I want each of the colors to be different (grey, blue, green, orange). However, the colors of the sections just take the first color (grey) in multiple brightnesses.

[image]

I also tried this in my `options`:

```
series: [
    {color: '#999'},
    {color: '#346ac9'},
    {color: '#279423'},
    {color: '#fc9826'}
]
```

How do I get each of the series to have a different color?

Comment: The `colors` option seems to be working for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5j54L2nL/)

Answer (score 3):

At the time of the original question, the **Material Bar Chart** probably did not yet support custom colors for stacked bar charts.

Today, the `series` configuration option as an *array of color objects* seems to work fine.  See the `colors` variable in the example below.

Example code:

```
const data = [
   ['Sector',        'High', 'Medium', 'Low' ],
   ['Agriculture',   18,  9, 29],
   ['Education',      2, 14, 10],
   ['Healthcare',     4,  6, 41],
   ['Manufacturing', 36, 10,  3]
   ];
const colors = [
   { color: 'indianred' },  //high
   { color: 'khaki' },      //medium
   { color: 'seagreen' },   //low
   ];

const drawChart = () => {
   const options = {
      chart:   { title: 'Risk by sector' },
      legend:  { position: 'top' },  //not yet supported
      bars:    'horizontal',
      stacked: true,
      series:  colors
      };
   const chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
   const elem = $('figure#health-chart')[0];
   const chart = new google.charts.Bar(elem);
   chart.draw(chartData, options);
   };

google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Resulting chart:
[image: Bar Chart]

Fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/p8bnfe2h

**Configuration options**

> *`series`*
>   An array of objects, each describing the format of the corresponding series in the chart. To use default values for a series, specify an empty object {}. If a series or a value is not specified, the global value will be used.

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the colors working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5j54L2nL/2/)

When generating the graph I had to use: `new google.visualization.ColumnChart(...)` instead of `new google.charts.Bar(...)` otherwise it would not stack properly.

---

You may also want to make sure you are using the latest version of Google Charts. In the fiddle above, I used samples from the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) which were using: `https://www.google.com/jsapi` to autoload all the things.

Comment: Note that `google.visualization.ColumnChart()` is for the old **Classic** charts not the new **Material** charts.  Humans will have a permanent colony on Mars before Google gets **Material** charts figured out.